# Can I concat html dom elements

Tags: jquery, database

I would like to do something like

```
$(".form-horizontal").find("h3.tableName").html().join(',')
```

(I have my database tables in h3 dom)

and get a string output:

```
user,family,photo
```

Can I to it with a single line code or Im forced to do it with an array ?

Comment: Can you give us a bit more information about what you're trying to do? Ideally in the form of a [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it *runnable*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current logic doesn't work as jQuery returns an object from a selector, not an array. To solve this you  can use `map()` to retrieve data from a set of elements and place it in an array, like this:

```
var arr = $('.form-horizontal h3.tableName').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

If you want to retrieve a comma delimited string, you can then `join()` this array:

```
var str = arr.join(',');
```